# WinEdt: No .synctex file generated in a sudden

Tags: winedt

Some time in this week I found the inverse searching and forward searching functions are not working anymore. I checked the generated files and found that the .synctex files are no longer being generated. I have been using WinEdt for years and I don't think I changed any settings recently, so I have no idea what happens to it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: check the status line at the bottom. One of fields allows to switch synctex on and off.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was exactly my case. It was a little bit confusing that the --src option in the bottom was not visible when disabled.